# Producer Consumer in C

Tags: c, multithreading, homework, producer-consumer

I'm doing multithreading at university and we've been asked to implement the producer consumer problem in C.

My code compiles and produces the right result. From debugging it, it seems to be waiting for the semaphores to be freed etc. I'm using Xcode 6.4, hence the need for `sem_open()` instead of `sem_init()`. I just have a few questions regarding my code.

1. Have I done it correctly? Are there any mistakes/bugs?
2. If I wanted to make `buff` larger than one, would I set the semaphore `fre` to have an initial value of size `buff`? In the producer thread, would I have to call `sem_wait(fre)` `buff`times before I called `sem_post(busy)`? And then a similar thing in the consumer thread?

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

void * producer(void * b);
void * consumer(void * b);

void error(char msg) {
    perror(&msg);
    exit(1);
}

sem_t * fre, * busy;

int size_buff = 1;
char message[] = "Hello!";
int size_msg = sizeof(message);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    //declare threads
    pthread_t prod,con;
    int r;

    //create buffer and place it on the stack
    char * buff;
    buff = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * size_buff);


    //declare semaphores and initilise them
    char prod_name[] = "/Prod";
    char con_name[] = "/Con";
    fre = sem_open(prod_name, O_CREAT, 0777, 1);
    if ((int) fre == -1)
        error(errno);
    busy = sem_open(con_name, O_CREAT, 0777, 0);
    if ((int) fre == -1)
        error(errno);

    //start threads
    r = pthread_create(&prod, NULL, producer, (void *) buff);
    if (r) {
        error(r);
    }
    r = pthread_create(&con, NULL, consumer, (void *) buff);
    if (r) {
        error(r);
    }


    //unlink semaphores
    sem_unlink(prod_name);
    sem_unlink(con_name);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}

void * producer(void * b) {
    char * buff = (char *) b;
    int count = 0;

    //loop through message[] and write elements to buffer
    while (count < size_msg) {
        sem_wait(fre);
        strncat(buff,&message[count],1);
        sem_post(busy);
        count++;
    }

    return NULL;
}


void * consumer(void * b) {
    char * recv;
    recv = malloc(sizeof(char) * size_msg);
    char * buff = (char *) b;
    int count = 0;

    //read from the buffer
    while (count < size_msg) {
        sem_wait(busy);
        strncat(recv, buff, 1);
        memmove(buff, buff + 1, 1); //move the elements in the buffer along one, essentailly deleting the element just read
        sem_post(fre);
        count++;
    }
    printf("%s",recv);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Code Review! This is good first question and I hope you receive great answers!

Comment: Thank you for these! What are the other problems with it?

Comment: @user3629249 Maybe you should consolidate all of these comments into an answer...

Comment: moved all my prior comments to an answer.

Answer (score 5):

When calling the function `malloc()`:

1. The returned type is `void*`, so it can be assigned to any pointer, making the 'cast' totally unneeded. It just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.
2. The expression `sizeof(char)` is defined in the standard at 1. Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect, so the expression just clutters the code.
3. When calling any of the memory allocation functions (`malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`), always check (`!=NULL`) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

When invoking the `main()` function and the code does not use the parameters, use the signature `int main(void)`.

When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (For `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99`.)

For ease of understanding and readability by the reader of the code:

1. Separate code blocks (`for`, `if`, `else`, `while`, `do`...`while`, `switch`, `case`, `default`) via a blank line.
2. Use meaningful variable names. A variable name should indicate `usage` or `content` (or better, both).

The code is using 'named' semaphores. 'named' semaphores are persistent, so calling `sem_open()` with the `O_CREAT` parameter will fail if the file has ever been run before.  I suggest first calling `sem_unlink()`.

The calls to `error()` are not correct. The passed parameter is `errno`, a negative number, not a char and will not tell the user anything useful, especially if what is displayed is the contents of memory those address corresponds to the `errno` value. I suggest calling `syserror()` to get the error message that the OS thinks caused the error.

The call to `pthread_create()` returns 0 on success and -1 on failure. Passing that -1 to the function `error()` is meaningless.

I suggest passing a `char*` similar to `error("pthread_create for producer failed")` then modifying the `error()` function to expect a pointer to a `char` array.

The call to `sem_open()` returns a value `SEM_FAILED` which might be equal to -1 but that is an implementation detail, so do not use -1, use `SEM_FAILED`.

The second call to `sem_open()` returns busy, so the error check following that call should be checking `busy`, not `free`.

There are several other problems with the code, but the above comments should get you moving in the right direction.